# Would this array work to check letters entered by user?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

would this work as an array to check the letters entered by the user of the program?

```
final int LOW = 'A';  //smallest possible value
final int HIGH = 'Z';  //highest possible value

int[] letterCounts = new int[HIGH - LOW + 1];  
String guessletter;
char[] guessletter;
int offset;  //array index
// set constants for the secret word and also "!" to guess the full word
final String GUESS_FULL_WORD = "!";
final String SECRET_WORD = "APPLE";
// set integer value for number of letters for the length of the secret word
// set integer value for the number of guesses the user have made. starting at zero.
int numberofletters, numberofguesses;
numberofguesses = 0;

// guessletter indicates the letter that the user is guessing
// guessword indicates the word that the user is guessing after typing "!"
// new screen indicates the change made to the screen
// screen is the game screen that contains all the "_"'s
String guessletter, guessword, newscreen;
String screen = "";
numberofletters = SECRET_WORD.length ();

/* prompt user for a word */
c.print("Enter a letter: ");
guessletter = c.readLine();
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete (doesn't do anything useful).

Comment: Also, it doesn't compile, since you have three(!) declarations of `guessletter`...

Answer (score 0):

As @Bernard pointed out, the code you pasted doesn't do anything except ask the user for one letter. If your question is whether you are on the right track with regard to keeping track of which letters the user has guessed (so that the program won't accept a letter that has already been guessed), then yes, you can use `letterCounts` for that, by incrementing the array element that corresponds to the letter that the user guessed. If you are stuck on something, you should be more clear about what the problem is.